# If we change text-domain of plugin, does it effect old user translations?

Tags: wordpress, internationalization

Due to the conflict between the .org plugin slug and text-domain of my plugin, community translations doesn't work as intended. For e.g I have `content-management-system` as plugin slug and my current text-domain is `my-cms`. I have to now update the tex-domain to `content-management-system`. Does this will effect old users who have already translated the plugin with my-cms.pot file? If yes, then please suggest how can i deal with this?

One possible solution is to rename the community translated files from content-management-system-np_NP.po to my-cms-np_NP.po and place to it language folder but everytime it is not possible to update the file.